# SDN4 - MappingException thrown when using an interface as the end of a RelationshipEntity

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

This functionality was working at one point but seems to have broken in the latest SDN4 snapshot (7-16-15)

I have two node classes, one representing intermediate, non-leaf nodes and one representing leaf vertex nodes of degree one.  The two classes implement a common interface.

```
public interface Node {
    ...
}

@NodeEntity
public class SimpleNode implements Node {
    ...
}

@NodeEntity
public class SimpleLeafNode implements Node {
    ...
}
```

The former can be related to other intermediate nodes OR leaf nodes and I have modeled this relationship by mapping the `SimpleNode` class to the `Node` INTERFACE:

```
@RelationshipEntity
public class SimpleRelationship {

    @StartNode
    private SimpleNode parent;

    @EndNode
    private Node child;
}
```

When I try to start up my Spring Boot application, I receive an SDN mapping exception:

```
Caused by:
    10:51:04.173 [DEBUG] org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MappingException: No identity field found for class: com.sdn4demo.entity.Node
    10:51:04.174 [DEBUG]    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.info.ClassInfo.identityField(ClassInfo.java:291)
    10:51:04.174 [DEBUG]    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty.<init>(Neo4jPersistentProperty.java:76)
    10:51:04.174 [DEBUG]    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(Neo4jMappingContext.java:100)
```

Again, this was working before the 7-16-15 snapshot so my questions is - is this not supported functionality?  Is this a bug?

A contrived example exists at:
https://github.com/simon-lam/sdn-4-demo

Reproduce-able by doing `./gradlew clean test --debug`

Comment: Worked around by using 4.0.0.RC1 for now, fellow teammate pointed out that there was a RC rel.  Nonetheless I think this may still be an open issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug.  We're currently working on sorting stuff out regarding SD-commons and Spring DATA REST integration and this is one of those consequences of using the bleeding edge stuff.

Using RC1 is probably the best bet for now.  Keep an eye on this JIRA issue to see when it's completed:  https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-564